# Probabilty of Event A and Event B at least then at most assuming the newpepar Predictions are correct?

Tags: probability

A two-day conference is going to be held in a city. The leading newspaper in the city says there is a 10% chance of rain on the first day of the conference and a 40% chance of rain on the second day. If the newspapers are correct then:
i) Find the chance that it rains in the city during the conference is:
My approach is product rule of two days events P(A) and P(B)=
P((A) first day rain and (B) second day rain ) = P (A)*P (B)= (.10)*(.40)=.04=4%> 0% at least <10%?, 
ii-)If the newspaper’s figures are correct, , the chance that it rains in the city during the conference is Compliment Rule P(A and Bat the most)=(1-P(i)=1-0.04=0.96=96% therefore 40%<50%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the newspaper doesn't give enough information.  You can't multiply the probabilities because the events $A$ and $B$ are not known to be independent (and indeed are almost certainly dependent).  The best you can say is that $P(A \cup B) \ge P(B) = 0.4$ and
$P(A \cup B) \le P(A) + P(B) = 0.5$.  It would be $0.4$ if $A \subset B$ (i.e. if it rains on the first day it must also rain on the second day), and it would be $0.5$ if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint (i.e. it can't rain on both days).

Comment: Thanks Robert Israel for Your straight forward solution in a difficult problem! Thanks Again Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Like many probability problems wrapped in a "real world" cloak, this problem expects us to make unreasonable assumptions.

So we will assume that the probability it rains on Day $1$ is indeed $0.1$, and the probability it rains on Day $2$ is $0.4$, and the events "rain on Day $1$" and "rain on Day $2$" are **independent**. This last assumption is quite unreasonable.

But, holding our noses, let's calculate.

The probability it *doesn't* rain on Day $1$ is $0.9$, and the probability it *doesn't* rain on Day $2$ is $0.6$. So by independence, the probability **both** days are dry is $(0.9)(0.6)$.

Thus the probability of rain on at least one of the days is $1-(0.9)(0.6)$.